# How do I 'get' messages from MQ using Apache camel?

Tags: java, apache-camel, ibm-mq

I have created an application which I can use to put messages on MQ. This is a REST api created with Springboot and Apache Camel.
Now I want to create an application which gets the messages that are on MQ. The problem is that I can't find any documentation or examples.

I thought first it would just be a matter of recreating the API, but with a get method. The problem is that the I then receive an error that my app doesn't have access to the queue and I don't receive any messages back.

Does anyone has experience with this or can guide me to docs/examples?
I tried looking for it on Stackoverflow but I only see Post examples.

Answer (score 0):

The [MQ documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=api-getting-started-messaging-rest) tells how to get a message with the REST API. It is by using a DELETE request (which is appropriate as it destructively gets the message).
You say you receive an error indicating your app doesn't have access to the queue. Maybe you have only be granted to put a message to this queue. The documentation referenced above also tells what authorization you need to get a message.